# Iterators and lists

Tags: list, iterator, zip

Can anyone explain this paragraph to me? I just can't seem to get it.

"A zip object is a kind of iterator, which is any object that iterates through a sequence.
Iterators are similar to lists in some ways, but unlike lists, you can’t use an index to select
an element from an iterator".

Python 3.0

Comment: It is a great question.  But it prob. takes some great length of words to explain the *intricacy* details.  Maybe start reading this article - https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/  first.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have gotten the concept now

Comment: Welcome to S/O. come back with some more *great* questions.. You may find this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask